# Bind content containing html tags

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

How can I display content containing html tags like `<br>` inside a polymer-element like:

```html
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    {{mylongtext}}
  </template>
<script ...></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
@CustomTag("my-element")
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  @observable string mylongtext = "bla bla <br> bla bla <strong> bla </strong>";
}
```

Currently those tags are shown as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention, `mylongtext` is simply displayed as a string, it's not specifically an element or even mark up. However what we can do is automatically call a function any time that our observable is changed. In the callback we create a [DocumentFragment](http://api.dartlang.org/dart_html/DocumentFragment.html) which is based off of the contents of the string, and then insert that into our div container.

```html
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
  </template>
<script ...></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
@CustomTag("my-element")
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  @observable string mylongtext = "bla bla <br> bla bla <strong> bla </strong>";

  MyElement() {
    // Bind property changes to the mylongtext observable string and 
    onPropertyChange(this, #mylongtext, addFragment);
  }

  // Need to do it on inserted to ensure we add the initial value.
  void inserted() {
    super.inserted();
    addFragment();
  }

  void addFragment() {
    var df = new DocumentFragment.html(mylongtext);
    // In the clear any contents from container and add new fragment
    $['container'].nodes..clear()..add(df);
  }

}
```

Note that [`onPropertyChange`](http://api.dartlang.org/observe.html#onPropertyChange) and the [`$[..]`](http://api.dartlang.org/polymer/PolymerElement.html#%24) automatic node finding require Polymer dart 0.8.0 or higher (in previous versions it's `bindProperty` and using `shadowRoot.query(..)` respectively).

One thing to keep in mind however, is that using `DocumentFragment.html()` and other similar string-to-html parsers is that they are subject to Sanitization as discussed in [this breaking change](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/kQD2-_hY_DQ/discussion).

Comment: This still works the same. I created a Polymer 1.0 version of such an element. The source is available in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_bind_html) of `<bwu-bind-html>`

Answer (score 2):

This was in web-ui, but is [not yet supported](https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/issues/57) in [polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) and thus not in [polymer.dart](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/) yet either.  Idea from [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web-ui/joETEQ4pV9w/QFeLld3BjycJ) was to create a safe-html element:

```html
<safehtml>{{bindSafeHtmlHere}}</safehtml>
```