# Bind text with line breaks

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a binding to a string with a line break, like `'Hello\nWorld'` in my model. Now I want to display the value in my template using `{{x}}`. But the line break is not correctly displayed. Does polymer provide any support for outputting `<br>` for line breaks?

Comment: This seems to be the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316300/bind-content-containing-html-tags which alredy got some answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your best option would be to create a `Nl2br` `PolymerElement`. The only place you can add mark up is inside of the template, so you'll need a template to split the string and add the `<br />`s

**Example:**

```html
 <nl2br-element text="{{}}"></nl2br-element>
```

**nl2br.dart**

```dart
library nl2br;

import "dart:html";
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import "package:polymer_expressions/polymer_expressions.dart";

@CustomTag('nl2br-element')
class Nl2brElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  @observable String text;

  DocumentFragment instanceTemplate(Element template) =>
      template.createInstance(this,
          new PolymerExpressions(globals: {
            'splitnewline': (String input) => input.split("\n")
          }));
}
```

**nl2br.html**

```html
<polymer-element name="nl2br-element" attributes="text">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{line in text | splitnewline}}">
      {{line}}<br />
    </template>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="nl2br.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**nl2br_test.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="nl2br.html">
    <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <template id="nl2br" bind>
      <nl2br-element text="{{}}"></nl2br-element>
    </template>

    <script type="application/dart" src="nl2br_test.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**nl2br_test.dart**

```dart
library nl2br_test;

import 'dart:html';

main() {
  query("#nl2br").model = "foo\nbar";
}
```

You can create a polymer expression that will replace `\n` with `<br />`. 
Right now, polymer sanitizes all html and you can't get around it without DOM manipulation. Since it will make `<br />` html safe, `foo\nbar` will display exactly as `foo&lt;br /&gt;bar` on the page without showing a line break. **Which means this won't do exactly what you want**, but if polymer adds a way to display safe html on the page, this would be the way to go.

```dart
library nl2br_mixin;

import "dart:html";
import "package:polymer_expressions/polymer_expressions.dart";

class Nl2brMixin {
  DocumentFragment instanceTemplate(Element template) =>
    template.createInstance(this,
        new PolymerExpressions(globals: {
          'nl2br': (String input) => input.replaceAll("\n", "<br />")
        }));
}
```

You can use this mixin with your PolymerElement

```dart
class CustomElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin, Nl2brMixin {
  @observable
  String text = "foo\nbar";
}
```

And use the nl2br expression in your template

```
{{text | nl2br}}
```

Now this probably isn't the best way to get the `nl2br` expression in your custom element without explicitly putting it in your class. If you have multiple mixins that declare `instanceTemplate` or declare it in your class, only one of them will work.

Comment: Nice answer, for now I'm using the solution from this anwser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19324203/218902 Later, after the polymer support is available, I should switch to your answer.

Comment: OK, decided to use your first solution, but without an additional custom element, to reduce the dependencies on additional elements. Integrating the solutions into my existing element works fine, thanks!