# instanceTemplate in polymer 0.8.7

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

This question is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338220/bind-text-with-line-breaks). After upgrading to polymer 0.8.7 the following code stopped working:

```dart
  DocumentFragment instanceTemplate(Element template) =>
      template.createInstance(this,
          new PolymerExpressions(globals: {
            'splitnewline': (String input) => input.split("\n")
          }));
```

Looks like `Element` doesn't contain a method `createInstance` anymore. How can I register a own polymer expression in polymer 0.8.7?

PS: I also used the method `job()` in the past, does anybody know where I can find it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With polymer 0.8.7 you have to import an additional package and call `templateBind` on the element.

```dart
import 'package:template_binding/template_binding.dart';

// ... fancy code in between ...

DocumentFragment instanceTemplate(Element template) =>
  templateBind(template).createInstance(this,
      new PolymerExpressions(globals: {
        'splitnewline': (String input) => input.split("\n")
      }));
```

Don't know about the `job()` method though.