# Polymer 1.x nl2br, or the quest to validating html in templates

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In a custom element template, assume a string such as `hello\world` stored as `this.foo`.

How may I replace `\n` by `<br />` ?

Several posts found on SE mention Juicy (https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-html)
Others use a custom element as a wrapper (see [Bind text with line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338220/bind-text-with-line-breaks/19407264#19407264))

But isn't there a more straightforward method, what about doing something like:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{bubbles}}">
  <li><span class="content">{{getContent(item)}}</span></li>
</template>
```

And

```
getContent: function(item) {
    return item.content.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />")
}
```

Problem is that the `<br />` isn't evaluated as an HTML element

So isn't there a proper way to validate a string against certain allowed tags (`br` in this case), or must I really go the Juicy way ?

What do you think ? ;)

Comment: It gets computed as `HTML` if you use `innerHTML` property see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060890/how-to-assign-html-entities-in-polymer-element-definition). I know you are calling it from function, but see if you can use this.

Comment: Well, yes, this is the equivalent of using a dummy wrapper element around the content. This is a possibility, but.. It feels like using a bazooka to shoot a fly :/
I wonder if there is a way to validate that HTML and inject it, like many fw do when injecting HTML into templates...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it seems the best (and only?) way to achieve this right now is to pass the HTML string as an argument to my custom-element, than use `innerHTML` to inject the HTML in said custom-element...

Which is exactly what Juicy (https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-html) does.

Conclusion, either use `innerHTML` yourself in your custom-element, or use Juicy ;)