# HTML Tags Within Internationalized Strings In Polymer.dart

Tags: internationalization, dart, dart-polymer, dart-html

I am displaying internationalized strings within a Polymer element as follows:

```html
<div>
  <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
  <br/><br/>
  <span class="subtitle">{{subtitle1}}</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="content">{{paragraph1}}</span>
  <br/><br/>
  <span class="subtitle">{{subtitle2}}</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="content">{{paragraph2}}</span>
</div>
```

... and have the following dart code:

```dart
@observable String title;
@observable String subtitle1;
@observable String paragraph1;
@observable String subtitle2;
@observable String paragraph2;

//...

void onUpdateLocale(_locale) {
  title = getTitle();
  subtitle1 = getSubtitle1();
  paragraph1 = getParagraph1();
  subtitle2 = getSubtitle2();
  paragraph2 = getParagraph2();
}

//...

getTitle() => Intl.message('MY TITLE', name:'title',
    desc: 'This is my title',
    args: [],
    examples: {'None' : 0});
getSubtitle1() => Intl.message('Subtitle 1', name:'subtitle1',
    desc: 'This is my first subtitle',
    args: [],
    examples: {'None' : 0});
getParagraph1() => Intl.message('This is my first paragraph',
    name:'paragraph1',
    desc: 'This is the my first paragraph',
    args: [],
    examples: {'None' : 0});
getSubtitle2() => Intl.message('Subtitle 2', name:'subtitle1',
    desc: 'This is my second subtitle',
    args: [],
    examples: {'None' : 0});
getParagraph2() => Intl.message('This is my second paragraph',
    name:'paragraph2',
    desc: 'This is the my second paragraph',
    args: [],
    examples: {'None' : 0});
```

Is there a way to combine `title`, `subtitle1`, `paragraph1`, `subtitle2`, and `paragraph2` into one observable variable that includes the `<br>` and `<span>` tags in its value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind content containing html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316300/bind-content-containing-html-tags)

Comment: Thanks, Günter. Do you know what the safe-html polymer element would look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

A ready-to-use element for Dart Polymer 1.0 is [bwu-bind-html](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_bind_html)

---

**Update**

Polymer now provides support for this out of the box

```dart
 this.injectBoundHTML('<div>your HTML goes here ${someBoundFieldValue}</div>);
```

**Old**

This is the code of the `<safe-html>` tag I'm using.

```dart
library safe_html;

import 'dart:async';
import "dart:html";

import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";


@CustomTag("safe-html")
class SafeHtml extends PolymerElement  {

  @published String model;

  NodeValidator nodeValidator;
  bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;
  bool isInitialized = false;

  SafeHtml.created() : super.created() {
    nodeValidator = new NodeValidatorBuilder()
    ..allowTextElements();
  }

  void modelChanded(old) {
    if(isInitialized) {
      _addFragment();
    }
  }

  void _addFragment() {
    var fragment = new DocumentFragment.html(model, validator: nodeValidator);
    $["container"].nodes
    ..clear()
    ..add(fragment);

  }

  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    Timer.run(() {
      _addFragment();
      isInitialized = true;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<polymer-element name="safe-html"> 
  <template>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart" src='safe_html.dart'></script>

</polymer-element>
```

usage:

```html
<safe-html model="{{someField}}></safe-html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Günter.  When I use your element as `<safe-html model="{{myContent}}"><safe-html>` I am getting the following errors and the content doesn't pick up the style.

    `Removing disallowed attribute <SPAN class="content">
    Removing disallowed attribute <SPAN class="subtitle">
    Removing disallowed attribute <SPAN class="content">
    Removing disallowed attribute <SPAN class="subtitle">
    Removing disallowed attribute <SPAN class="content">`

Comment: You can customize the NodeValidator. I added the line `        ..allowElement('SPAN', attributes: ['class']);` as an example (not actually tried it - hope it works anyway)

Comment: `allowHtml5()` apparently excludes "script elements, style attributes and any script handlers" ( [from API dartdoc](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/be/latest/dart_html/NodeValidatorBuilder.html#allowHtml5) ).

Comment: Credit for this element goes to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316300 (just stumbled upon again)