# How can I bind a text which contains url as html

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

How can I bind a text which contains url as html. Is it possible by using the following code ?

```dart
@CustomTag('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {      
  @observable String text = "Bla bla bla '<a href="mysite.com">link</a>';"

  MyElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

```html
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <template>
  <p>
   {{text}}
  </p>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

A ready-to-use element for Dart Polymer 1.0 is [bwu-bind-html](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_bind_html)

---

No you can't bind html using mustache.

what you can do is

```dart
<a href="{{text}}">link</a>
```

with a field like

```dart
@observable String text = "mysite.com";
```

or use something like a `<safe-html>` tag - see [HTML Tags Within Internationalized Strings In Polymer.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868296)

Comment: It seems that the tag <a> is not allowed..  I get the message "Removing disallowed element <A>". Why not?

Comment: See the comments below the `<safe-html>` code in my answer. You need to customize the `NodeValidator` settings. The passed NodeValidator specifies which tags and which attributes on those tags are allowed. There are some predefined settings in `NodeValidator` like `allowHtml5()` (I think that should enable the `<a>` tag too, but you also can enable individual tags).