# Disable escaping HTML in data-binding when using repeat-templates in Polymer

Tags: html, data-binding, dart, polymer

Hello folks,

```
        <template repeat="{{amendment in amendments}}">
            <div layout horizontal>
              <div>{{amendment['proposed_text']}}</div>
              <div>{{amendment['amendment_text'])}</div>
            </div>
        </template>
```

`proposed_text` and `amendment_text` contain HTML content such as `<br>`. Since Polymer escapes all HTML content when using data binding, these `<br>` Tags are not shown. I googled for quiete a while and came up with `injectBoundHTML(expression, element)` which however also doesn't work for me, since I don't have a single element but N elements which are created by the `repeat` template.

My questions as you may guess is, how can I make these `<br>` or HTML in general visible in case of using a `repeat` template since `injectBoundHTML` doesnt seem to work here?

The solution I am currently using works in my case but won't work if the HTML content contains more than just `<br>`.

**My current solution:**

```
        <template repeat="{{amendment in amendments}}">
            <div layout horizontal>
              <div>
                <template repeat="{{text in splitAtBrs(amendment['proposed_text'])}}">
                  {{text}}<br>
                </template>
              </div>
              <div>
                <template repeat="{{text in splitAtBrs(amendment['amendment_text'])}}">
                  {{text}}<br>
                </template>
              </div>
            </div>
        </template>
```

with the method `splitAtBrs`:

```
 List<String> splitAtBrs(String s) {
    return s.split("\n");
  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058638/is-there-the-a-way-to-prevent-html-escaping-inside-a-polymer-expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my question above and checkout [Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058638/is-there-the-a-way-to-prevent-html-escaping-inside-a-polymer-expression) and [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830301/how-can-i-bind-a-text-which-contains-url-as-html) and especially [Answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868296/html-tags-within-internationalized-strings-in-polymer-dart). In answer #3 they use:

**.dart:**

```
String text = 'test<br/>foobar<br/><b>test</b>';
[...]
// somewhere in your code (e.g. in attached)
this.injectBoundHtml('xyz: ${text}', element: $['raw']);
```

**.html:**

```
<div id="raw"></div>
```

Maybe you can use this for template repeat as well, e.g. if you create your own function that will call *injectBoundHTML* for you.

Something like this would work:

```
int i = 0;
texts.forEach((String text) {
  this.injectBoundHtml('${text}', element: $['raw-${i}']);
  i++;
});
```

and in .html:

```
<template repeat="{{text in texts | enumerate}}">
  <div id="raw-{{text.index}}">{{text.index}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: But it might not be the best/most clean solution.