# Repeat over contents, polymer dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to loop over all children of a custom polymer element - for instance, to place each child in a new div.

```dart
<template repeat="{{child in children}}">
  <div>
    {{child}}
  </div>
</template>
```

When I try this, I get the toString() version of child, rather than the element itself. Is there a way to reference the element itself inside the repeat, rather than the result of its toString() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

A ready-to-use element for Dart Polymer 1.0 is [bwu-bind-html](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_bind_html)

---

This is not supported. Moustache binding can't insert HTML.

What you can do though is to use a Polymer element that provides that feature.
Please have look at my answer to [HTML Tags Within Internationalized Strings In Polymer.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868296) `<safe-html>`.

With this element your code would look like:

```dart
<template repeat="{{child in children}}">
  <div>
    <safe-html model="{{child}}"></safe-html>
  </div>
</template>
```

You might need to customize the NodeValidator construction which defines what kind of Elements are allowed to be added.

This feature might pose security risks (XSS) and is therefore not included in Polymer by default.

Comment: What is the recommended approach for such use-cases ? For instance, I need to create some custom-views (cards) in Dart (based on dynamic data), and would like to place those cards in a table view using Polymer. Should I create a new question for this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This approach is fine but when you use it you should be aware of the security implications. It is for example highly dangerous to bind user input for example loaded from a database using this element. If a user puts something like `<script> some malicious JavaScript</script>` in his `name` field and you show this using `<safe-html>` to other users (for example in a discussions section) this script is executed in every visitors browser. As long as you only bind static HTML or dynamic HTML constructed without any inclusion of any user input it is fine to use it.