# Creating Line Breaks in Dart

Tags: javascript, html, dart

I need to get make a break inside a string that will output in HTML;

```
String str = "Hello <br /> There";
```

would output:

```
Hello 
There
```

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific? What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: @SethLadd I have tried everything. All I want is to make a String with a break, then put it into an HTML element, such as a div, and make the text appear on more than 1 line.

Comment: You haven't shown what you tried and what the error was. That will really help us answer your question.

Comment: @SethLadd  With the above example in my question: no errors come up but only <br /> appears.

Comment: @SethLadd I don't know what else to try..

Comment: You could use something like `<safe-html>` tag shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20869025/217408

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
String str = "Hello\nThere";
```

instead.

Might need to apply `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap` to the style of the element where you're displaying the text, though.

Comment: Thanks for the brief and simple answer :) Just what I was looking for