# Auto convert html string to element

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Say I have a polymer-element `<polymer-element> <div id="foo"> {{html}} </div> </polymer-element>`, where `html` is supposed to be a HTML formated string, like `<p>blah</p>`, what I want is, when `html` changes, the polymer-element also changes, and use `html` as its innerHtml, i.e. auto convert the string to an element and insert it as foo's child.

Can polymer/polymer_expression do this for me, or I have to do a querySelector(), then set `html` as innerHtml manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is a custom element that extends a div and uses the DocumentFragment class to parse HTML strings into the DOM via data binding.

From my [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/montyr75/7739059)

```dart
<!-- Polymer Dart element that allows HTML to be inserted into the DOM via data binding -->

<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="html-display" extends="div">
  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'dart:html';
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

    @CustomTag('html-display')
    class HtmlDisplay extends DivElement with Polymer, Observable {
      @published String htmlContent;

      // we need this stuff because we're extending <div> instead of PolymerElement
      factory HtmlDisplay() => new Element.tag('div', 'html-display');
      HtmlDisplay.created() : super.created() {
        polymerCreated();
      }

      @override void attached() {
        super.attached();
      }

      // respond to any change in the "htmlContent" attribute
      void htmlContentChanged(oldValue) {
        if (htmlContent == null) {
          htmlContent = "";
        }

        // creating a DocumentFragment allows for HTML parsing
        this.nodes..clear()..add(new DocumentFragment.html("$htmlContent"));
      }
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<!--
Once you've imported the Polymer element's HTML file, you can use it from another Polymer element like so:

<link rel="import" href="html_display.html">

<div is="html-display" htmlContent="{{htmlString}}"></div>

*htmlString* can be something like "I <em>love</em> Polymer Dart!"
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I use solution as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20869025/789338.
The key class is `DocumentFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to do it is described in the doc: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#boundhtml

The example on the doc:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <div id="message_area"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      message: 'hi there',
      ready: function() {
        this.injectBoundHTML('<b>{{message}}</b>', this.$.message_area);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```