# Dartlang with polymer character encoding

Tags: character-encoding, dart, polymer

I wrote a snippet and not working with national characters.
The "A törzsszám"... text appear "tÃ¶rzsszÃ¡m" with my loginstatus field.

**Main html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="hu" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
....
```

**Login.html**

```dart
<polymer-element name="login-element" attributes="loginrow">
  <template>
    ...
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="{{torzsszam}}">
      ...
      <br>
      <span>({{loginstatus}})</span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="login.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

..and the **login.dart** snippet:

```dart
@CustomTag('login-element')
class Login extends PolymerElement {
  bool loginned = false;
  @published String torzsszam = "";
  @published String password = "";
  @published String loginstatus = "-";

  ...

  void log_in_click() {
    loginstatus="LOGIN";
    loginned = false;
    if (torzsszam != "" ) {
      if (torzsszam.length>8) {

        loginstatus='A törzsszám legfeljebb 8 számjegyből áll!';
      } else {
```

What can I do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago I posted the code for a `<safe-html>` tag at [HTML Tags Within Internationalized Strings In Polymer.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868296) (original form [Bind content containing html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316300))

Using this polymer element shows proper characters.

Your **login.html** would then look like:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../packages/safe_html/safe_html.html">

<polymer-element name="login-element" attributes="loginrow">
  <template>
    ...
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="{{torzsszam}}">
      ...
      <br>
      <span>(<safe-html model="{{loginstatus}}></safe-html>)</span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="login.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Just saw this only works for text written directly in the HTML markup.

Answer (score 2):

Ups,... 
I tried some solutions:

**1.solution:** change the encoding properties in *login.dart* from *utf-8* to *ISO-8859-2*

**2.solution:** I created another file (*consts.dart*)

```dart
class consts {
  static String loginstatus_err8 = "A törzsszám legfeljebb 8 számjegyből áll!";  
  static String loginstatus_OK = "Belépve";  
  static String loginstatus_emptytorzsszam = "A törzsszámot ki kell tölteni";
}
```

I used this in *login.dart*, and it worked :) I'm happy.

```dart
...
        loginstatus=consts.loginstatus_err8;
      } else {

        loginstatus=consts.loginstatus_OK;
...
```

Comment: After the latest Dart update this is no problem anymore. No need of safe-html just bind `{{myname}}` and shows national characters. (Dart VM version: 1.2.0-dev.1.0 (Fri Jan 17 19:12:36 2014) on "linux_x64")

Comment: It is still a problem, at least in Dart VM (the JavaScript version works fine). I just resolved it following the steps in this answer.