# Dart: how to resolve encoding in my custom Polymer element file

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have myelement.html file, where are placed templates for my custom polymer element.
Its content is like one shown below(just example):

```html
<polymer-element name = "welcome-box">

  <template>
    <p> Welcome šašo! </p>
  </template>

  <script type = "application/dart" src = "welcome-box.dart"> </script>

</polymer-element>
```

I have problem with encoding of this document. Various character that aren't in English alphabet (like 'ščžýáíé') don't display properly in my browser (despite the fact that index.html, file where previously mentioned polymer element is "imported", already **has** meta charset tag.

I solved this problem by adding meta charset tag to myelement.html

But I think that it's weird to declare meta charset again.

Is there any better solution how to solve encoding problem in my declaration of custom polymer element, except the duplicate  tags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dartlang with polymer character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134778/dartlang-with-polymer-character-encoding)

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the encoding, even though it's specified in the importing file, because you could import into multiple places. You wouldn't want a single file interpreted with a different encoding each time it was imported.