# I have greek text on a String in Dart using Polymer, why is it displayed wrongly on the browser?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following String on my Dart code, using Polymer:

```
@observable String title = "Καλώς Ήρθατε Ξανά!";
```

But this is what I see on the browser:

```
ÎšÎ±Î»ÏŽÏ‚ Î‰ÏÎ¸Î±Ï„Îµ ÎžÎ±Î½Î¬!
```

What am I missing ?

When the text uses the regular Latin chars, everything is perfect.

Thank you in forward

Comment: You may take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868296

Comment: @Gunter: How does that question relate to my problem? Maybe you can point me out how he solves using non-latin chars on that example.

Comment: Sorry this was not actually the question I wanted to link. There was a question about eastern europe characters with probably the same problem as yours but I can't find it now. But I offered the same solution as in the linked question and as far as I remember it solved the problem. The proposed solution uses a polymer-element `<safe-html>` to add the string using `nodes.add(fragment)` internally which handles encoding different than `{{...}}`. Instead of `{{title}}` you write `<safe-html model="{{title}}></safe-html>`. All needed code is provided in the answer.

Comment: This was the actual question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134778
This already worked but seems to be a bug again in Dartium as in @GV3 s answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Akshay comments on his response:

> It must be a bug in Dartium, I found this:
>   code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14948

I ran it as JS and the greek String was displayed properly. (With out the need of any Encoding or else, just with the String).

So, I ran the JS version on the Chromium browser just to check... maybe it was a Browser issue.... but it ALSO WORKED!

The solution is: There is no solution... IT's a bug on the Dartium, (see link above).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Import:**

```
import 'dart:convert' show UTF8;
```

**Code:**

```
List<int> encoded = UTF8.encode('Καλώς Ήρθατε Ξανά!');
@observable String title = UTF8.decode(encoded);
```

**Short Code:**

```
@observable String title = UTF8.decode(UTF8.encode('Καλώς Ήρθατε Ξανά!'));
```

This should encode your string as `UTF8` so it shows up properly on screen.

Comment: It seems the UTF.encode(String input) returns a List<int>.

It throws me the error= "A value of type 'List<int>' cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'String'"

Comment: Also trying to get the first child of the List brings me nowhere... cause it's a List<int> and not a List<String>

But I strongly believed that there was somewhere a converter that would help me out.

Comment: Now I don't have any error regarding the encoder... but the result on the screen is still the same: ÎšÎ±Î»ÏŽÏ‚ Î‰ÏÎ¸Î±Ï„Îµ ÎžÎ±Î½Î¬!

Comment: In the heading of your html add this: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: I already had the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` on the `<head>` tag

Comment: So, I had the feeling that something was odd ... and that the problem might be there only when I run it in Dartium, so I decided to run it as JS and it worked as I originally wrote it. With out the need of any Encoding or else, just with the String. Then I ran the JS version on the Chromium browser just o check... and it ALSO WORKED! So I pressume it the error is related to running it in Dartium. Any ideas about that?

Comment: @GV3 It must be a bug in Dartium, I found this: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14948

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with French.
Set the charset into your HTML file header (default is ISO-8859-1)

Short:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Long:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

This should solve this issue. BTW all strings in Dart are already in UTF8

Comment: Sorry @eric but this did't solved the problem. I believe the BUG mentioned before is still the reason why...