# Are there ways to display Korean, Japanese or Chinese characters on polymer paper-item?

Tags: polymer

I am using polymer to develop my own app. Coz the target user are Asian, i have to use Korean, Japanese or Chinese characters. However, they are not display properly.[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li9x3.png)

Are there ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790895/i-have-greek-text-on-a-string-in-dart-using-polymer-why-is-it-displayed-wrongly or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134778/dartlang-with-polymer-character-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding in the HTML file of the Polymer element.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

See also [I have greek text on a String in Dart using Polymer, why is it displayed wrongly on the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790895/i-have-greek-text-on-a-string-in-dart-using-polymer-why-is-it-displayed-wrongly)