# Escaping characters ever necessary in AngularDart?

Tags: escaping, dart, angular-dart

Does one ever have to worry about character escaping in AngularDart? I think that mustache rendering is always safe; e.g.

```html
<span>{{ctrl.recipe.name}}</span>
```

Can someone confirm that? Any other situations a greenhorn needs to be aware of?

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Which characters would you need to escape?

Answer (score 4):

All content in AngularDart is escaped. `{{expression}}` results in string which is written using non-`innerHTML` API, and thus the browser escapes it.

Answer (score 3):

You are right.
If `ctrl.recipe.name` would contain 'dangerous' content it would be stripped.
You need a NodeValidator to specify which HTML elements/attributes are allowed.

see also:

- [Bind content containing html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316300)
- [HTML Tags Within Internationalized Strings In Polymer.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868296)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be stripping, it's escaping. A quick seems to show that < is turned into &lt;, etc.

Comment: If you use `appendText` it's escaping, with `setInnerHtml`, `innerHtml`, `append`, `appendHtml` it's stripping.

Comment: It will not be stripped, it is escaped.