# render text as html while iterating in polymer table

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

how to render text as html

```dart
<polymer-element name = "table-element" attributes ="structure data">
     <template>
         <table class="ui table segment" id="table_element">
             <tr>
                 <th template repeat="{{col in cols}}">
                     {{col}}
                 </th>
             </tr>
             <tr template repeat="{{row in data}}">
                **<td template repeat="{{field in fields}}">
                   {{row[field]}} // render this as html
                 </td>**
             </tr>
         </table>
     </template>
<script type="application/dart" src="table_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

below text

```dart
"<a href=\"http://google.com\"> open</a>"
```

is rendered as plain text `<a href="http://google.com"> open</a>` inside table ,how to make this rendered as html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

A ready-to-use element for Dart Polymer 1.0 is [bwu-bind-html](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_bind_html)

---

You can use something like a `<safe-html>` element shown here:

- [Bind content containing html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316300)
- [HTML Tags Within Internationalized Strings In Polymer.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868296)

Comment: There is also an enhancement request about that:
https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/issues/57